# meekrodb: how to perform a replace with where statement instead of primary key

Tags: php, mysql

I am using the php/mysql library, **meekrodb**.

I want to update an existing row if 3 field conditions are met; otherwise insert a new row.

***PROBLEM***:

```
An "update" will not create a new row if a current one does not exist.
An "insert" will insert a redundant row even if a current row already exists.
A "replace" requires a primary key.
```

Currently, it seems that I will have to perform 2 queries: one to check for the existence of a row in question ... and then if it does exist to perform an update query; otherwise an insert query.

**GOAL**: a replace statement *that accepted a where clause* instead of depending on a primary key ...

```
$where = new WhereClause( 'and' ); 
$where->add( 'field_A=%s'    , 'aaaa' ) ;
$where->add( 'field_B=%s'    , 'bbbb' ) ;
$where->add( 'field_C=%s'    , 'cccc' ) ;

DB::replace( 'my_table', 
             array( 'field_A' => 'aaaa' ,
                    'field_B' => 'bbbb' ,
                    'field_C' => 'cccc' ,
                    'field_D' => 'dddd'  
                   ) ,
             $where

           );
```

Answer (score 0):

Your statement that "An "update" will not create a new row if a current one does not exist." is incorrect.

The goal you are trying to achieve will be achieved with an UPDATE query. If the conditions are not met, a new row will be inserted, else the matching fields will be updated.